How to Enable BLE Scanning in the Background on iOS
I am trying to implement background BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) scanning in an iOS app using CoreBluetooth. When my app is in the foreground, I can successfully scan and collect BLE device data. However, when the app goes into the background or the phone is locked, the scanning does not function as expected. The app doesn’t receive BLE data in the background. I want to scan and send the BLE to a server every 20 seconds when a location background update is made. Here is an overview of my setup:
The BluetoothManager:
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

struct BluetoothDevice {
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral
    var rssi: NSNumber
    var advertisementData: [String: Any]
    var manufacturerData: Data?
    var major: UInt16?
    var minor: UInt16?
}

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    @Published var discoveredDevices: [BluetoothDevice] = []
    @Published var connectedPeripherals: [CBPeripheral: [CBService]] = [:] // To store services for each peripheral
    @Published var isScanning: Bool = false
    
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func startScanning() {
        if !isScanning {
            isScanning = true
            discoveredDevices.removeAll()
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
            
            // Stop scanning after 2 seconds
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.stopScanning()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopScanning() {
        if isScanning {
            centralManager.stopScan()
            isScanning = false
            print("Stopped scanning for devices")
        }
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            startScanning()
        } else {
            print("Bluetooth is not available.")
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        // Extract manufacturer data if available
        guard let manufacturerData = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] as? Data else {
            return
        }
        
        // Assuming this is an iBeacon-like device
        let manufacturerDataHex = manufacturerData.hexEncodedString().lowercased()
        
        // Filter: Check if manufacturer data contains "7e10ca7"
        if manufacturerDataHex.contains("exampleHexNumber") {
            var majorValue: UInt16? = nil
            var minorValue: UInt16? = nil
            
            // Check if the data length is enough to contain major and minor values
            if manufacturerData.count >= 24 {
                // Extract major and minor values
                let majorRange = 20..<22
                let majorData = manufacturerData.subdata(in: majorRange)
                majorValue = UInt16(bigEndian: majorData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt16.self) })
                
                let minorRange = 22..<24
                let minorData = manufacturerData.subdata(in: minorRange)
                minorValue = UInt16(bigEndian: minorData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt16.self) })
                
                // Check if this device is already in discoveredDevices
                if let existingIndex = discoveredDevices.firstIndex(where: { $0.peripheral.identifier == peripheral.identifier }) {
                    // Update RSSI of the existing device
                    discoveredDevices[existingIndex].rssi = RSSI
                } else {
                    // Add new device if it's not already in discoveredDevices
                    let device = BluetoothDevice(
                        peripheral: peripheral,
                        rssi: RSSI,
                        advertisementData: advertisementData,
                        manufacturerData: manufacturerData,
                        major: majorValue,
                        minor: minorValue
                    )
                    discoveredDevices.append(device)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        //print("Connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown Device")")
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        if let services = peripheral.services {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.connectedPeripherals[peripheral] = services // Store the discovered services
                self.updateDeviceList() // Notify that the list needs to be updated
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateDeviceList() {
        objectWillChange.send() // Notify the UI that the data has changed
    }
    
    // Helper function to extract serial number (custom logic depending on your device data)
    func extractSerialNumber(from manufacturerData: Data?, advertisementData: [String: Any]) -> String {
        // Example logic: Try to extract from local name or parse specific part of manufacturer data
        if let localName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
            return "SN-\(localName)"
        } else if let manufacturerData = manufacturerData {
            // Example: Assume the serial number is stored in bytes 3-8 of manufacturer data (customize as per your device)
            let serialNumberData = manufacturerData.subdata(in: 2..<8)
            return serialNumberData.hexEncodedString().uppercased()
        } else {
            return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}

extension Data {
    /// Convert the manufacturer data to a hex string for easier reading
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
}

And the Location Manager:
import CoreLocation
import Foundation

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
    private var lastSentTimestamp: Date?  // Track the last time data was sent
    
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?
    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation?
    @Published var lastSuccessfulRequestDate: Date?  // New published property for last successful request
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(
        _ manager: CLLocationManager,
        didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]
    ) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        lastLocation = location
        
        // Check if we should send data based on the 20-second interval
        if shouldSendLocationData() {
            bluetoothManager.startScanning()  // Start Bluetooth scan
            
            // Delay sending location data to allow BLE scan to complete
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.sendLocationData(location)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(
        _ manager: CLLocationManager,
        didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus
    ) {
        self.locationStatus = status
    }
    
    private func shouldSendLocationData() -> Bool {
        if let lastSent = lastSentTimestamp {
            return Date().timeIntervalSince(lastSent) >= 20
        }
        return true
    }
    
    private func sendLocationData(_ location: CLLocation) {
        // Ensure we are respecting the interval check
        guard shouldSendLocationData() else { return }
        
        // Update the lastSentTimestamp after passing the interval check
        lastSentTimestamp = Date()
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://exampleurl.com/submit") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        let timestamp = Int(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970)
        
        let truncatedLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        let truncatedLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude

        // Collect BLE measurements with a single date for the BLE section
        let bleMeasurements = bluetoothManager.discoveredDevices.map { device -> [String: Any] in
            var measurement: [String: Any] = ["rssi": device.rssi.intValue]
            if let minor = device.minor {
                measurement["minor"] = minor
            }
            return measurement
        }
        
        // Create BLE data with one date and multiple measurements
        let bleData: [String: Any] = [
            "date": Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970),
            "measurements": bleMeasurements
        ]
        
        // Create GNSS data
        let gnssData: [String: Any] = [
            "date": timestamp,
            "data": [
                "latitude": truncatedLatitude,
                "longitude": truncatedLongitude
            ]
        ]
        
        // Construct the final JSON dict with both GNSS and BLE data
        let jsonDict: [String: Any] = [
            "ble": [bleData],  // Single BLE entry with one date and multiple measurements
            "gnss": [gnssData]
        ]
        
        // Convert data to JSON
        guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
            print("Failed to serialize JSON")
            return
        }
        
        // Print JSON as a debug output
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("JSON Payload:\n\(jsonString)")
        }
        
        guard let username = KeychainHelper.load(key: "name"),
              let password = KeychainHelper.load(key: "password") else {
            print("Credentials not found")
            return
        }
        
        let loginString = "\(username):\(password)"
        guard let loginData = loginString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("Failed to encode credentials")
            return
        }
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request
            .setValue(
                "Basic \(base64LoginString)",
                forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"
            )
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(
            with: request
        ) {
            data,
            response,
            error in
            if let error = error {
                print(
                    "Error sending location data: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                )
                return
            }
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                // Update last successful request date on success
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.lastSuccessfulRequestDate = Date()
                }
                
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
                let readableDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                
                print(
                    "Location and BLE data sent successfully at \(readableDate):"
                )
                print(
                    "Latitude: \(truncatedLatitude), Longitude: \(truncatedLongitude), Timestamp: \(timestamp)"
                )
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print(
                    "Failed to send location data. Status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                )
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}

My PLIST looks like:
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>bluetooth-le</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>

I am still unable to scan BLE devices reliably when the app is in the background.
Glad if someone can help here!

See linked duplicate. If you believe you have a different question not covered there, feel free to edit and we can reopen this. You need to list the specific services you're scanning for. You cannot scan for nil in the background. Generally there is no reason to drive this with location services for this. You can scan forever and the system will automatically launch your app when new devices advertising your service are seen (and this style of scanning is energy efficient). You can check location when you discover the device rather than starting and stopping scanning.
